# Unable to remove MarkerWithLabel

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google maps API with the MarkerWithLabel class. I'm unable to remove the markers after adding them to the map.

I have tried pushing them to an array and then iterating through it to remote them. At this point I'm just trying to remove them with setMap(null) right after adding them - to no avail.

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
    draggable: false,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    map: hotelsMap,
    label: 'label',
    labelContent: hotelName,
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(-13, 37),
    labelClass: "google-maps-label",
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
    title: hotelName });

marker.setMap(null);
```

This is what I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.label.setMap is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `label`-property.

This property will be set automatically based on the other properties(`labelContent` etc.) when you create the MarkerWithLabel.

Basically there is a conflict between the library and  the Maps-API:
there has been added a `label`-property to `google.maps.Marker` this year, but MarkerWithLabel(which extends `google.maps.Marker` ) also creates a `label`-property, but with different properties/methods, what results in the error.

Comment: Great - this was exactly it and fixed my issue!

Comment: Good call, I spent awhile trying to debug this. Good to know its an issues with the lib.

Comment: I was actually using the label, so couldn't remove it (showing both the standard one and the "markerswithlabel" custom one).

A simple fix was to add this condition at the end of the markersWithLabel.js file:  

**  if (this.label && this.label.setMap) { this.label.setMap(theMap); } **

Comment: How can i remove label -property. Explain in detail please.